# XML substituting special chars in C

Tags: c, string, memory-management, xml-parsing, malloc

I'm trying to develop a function in a library that looks for the caracters '<', '>' and '&'; and substitutes them for `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`.

So far, I've developed this function:

```
char *sXMLspecialReplace(char *rawString) {
  char *old_pointer = rawString;
  int new_index = 0;
  /*In most cases there won't be character substitution, so we can
  start allocating with the original length and only reallocate if
  a special char is spotted, therefore, memory reallocation will
  take place in few circumstances.
  + 1 for NULL terminator.*/
  int result_size = strlen(rawString) + 1;
  char *result = (char *) malloc(result_size);
  do {
    switch (*old_pointer) {
      case '&':
        result_size += 4; // From 1 to 5
        result = (char *) realloc(result, result_size);
        strcpy(result + new_index, "&amp;");
        new_index += 5;
        break;
      case '<':
        result_size += 3; // From 1 to 4
        result = (char *) realloc(result, result_size);
        strcpy(result + new_index, "&lt;");
        new_index += 4;
        break;
      case '>':
        result_size += 3; // From 1 to 4
        result = (char *) realloc(result, result_size);
        strcpy(result + new_index, "&gt;");
        new_index += 4;
        break;
      default:
        //Most frequent case
        result[new_index++] = *old_pointer;
    }
    old_pointer++;
  } while (*old_pointer != '\0');
  /*do-while ensures the function exits with a null terminator*/
  return result;
}
```

While it works in some cases, there are others when it doesn't work. In a test I tried to do the following:

```
char *my_company = "HELLO INDUSTRIES EUROPE";
char *xml_company = sXMLspecialReplace(my_company);

sprintf(sXMLanswer,
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
  "<company>%s</company>\n",
  xml_company);

printf(sXMLanswer);
```

OUTPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>HELLO INDUSTRIES EUROPE[[[[[</company>
```

EDIT 1: format `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`.

Comment: First of all, please read [this discussion about casting the result of `malloc` (and friends like `realloc`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Secondly, never reassign back to the pointer variable you pass to `realloc`, if `realloc` fails your original pointer will be lost. Thirdly, don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-termination* is important, and requires an extra byte, making a four-character string need space for five characters.

Comment: I agree with the first two points. However, I think the third point is taken into account in the initial `malloc`, which uses the lenght of the parameter `raw_string` + 1.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I do. When the pointer gets to the NULL terminator of `raw_string`, this NULL character is copied into `result`, then the exit condition is met, and the function returns. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The space for the terminating character was included properly: `int result_size = strlen(rawString) + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not nul-terminate your copy of the string.

```
do
{
  switch (*old_pointer)
  {
   ...
    default:
      //Most frequent case
      result[new_index++] = *old_pointer;
  }
  old_pointer++;
} while (*old_pointer != '\0');
```

In your `switch` you copy the characters. Afterwards you advance your source pointer. 
And then you check if the advanced pointer points to `'\0'`.
This means after the last character of the string you leave the `do while` loop and do not copy the terminating `'\0'` byte.

This leaves random garbage after your copy of the string.

You might fix it like this:

```
  ...
  }
  // No incement here!
} while (*old_pointer++ != '\0');
```

Comment: This is the explanation and the solution works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better(1) to do what you want in three separate step :

- 1 : get the len of the final result
- 2 : Allocate it
- 3 : fill it

To get the final len, it's pretty simple : You just iterate over the string and each time you see the character you want to replace, you increase the len accordingly.

To fill it, it's pretty simple too : You iterate over the string again, and if you see a character, you add the substitute text instead of the original char.

Given what you have already did, I think this algorithm will be a piece of cake for you.

If you want to keep it realy basic, you can harcode everything (like you already did), or you can use structure to allow a more evolutif code (like addind another character to replace).

Edit : (1) I say "better" because you may end up doing a lot of realloc/malloc at runtime, which is not really efficient at all. Futhermore, each time you want to add a replacement character (I don't know if XML have other than "&<>"), you will have to do a realloc, which will increase your code for nothing.
Imagine having 23 charactere to replace ... Your code will end up in a hell of maintenance.

---

```
typedef struct swap {
    char   src;
    char   *dst;
    size_t dstLen;
} swap_s;

swap_s *SwapList_FoundBySrc(swap_s *list, char searched)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; list[i].src; ++i) {
        if (list[i].src == searched) {
            return (&list[i]);
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}

char *PlainStringToXmlString(char *input)
{
    char   *output = NULL;
    size_t len     = 1; // Final '\0'
    swap_s list[]  = {{'&',  "&amp;", strlen("&amp;")},
                      {'<',  "&lt;",  strlen("&lt;")},
                      {'>',  "&gt;",  strlen("&gt;")},
                      {'\0', NULL,    0}};
    swap_s *swap   = NULL;

    // Get the final len sum
    for (size_t i = 0; input[i]; ++i) {
        if ((swap = SwapList_FoundBySrc(list, input[i]))) {
            len += swap->dstLen;
        } else {
            ++len;
        }
    }

    // Allocate it
    if (!(output = malloc(len))) {
        // Log ?
        return (NULL);
    }
    output[len - 1] = '\0';

    // Fill it
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; input[i]; ++i) {
        if ((swap = SwapList_FoundBySrc(list, input[i]))) {
            strcpy(output + j, swap->dst);
            j += swap->dstLen;
        } else {
            output[j] = input[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }

    return (output);
}
```